# How to fix "canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap error"?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, android-glide

I'm creating a `RecyclerView` to show a Grid of pictures. When selecting one of them, it should open a new activity with a transition.

I'm using Glide library to load the pictures and the transition looks awful because it reloads the picture in the new activity. So I had to save it in cache, and then use it for the transition.

I have the code, but sometimes if the picture doesn't load, it throws a Canvas RuntimeException.

This is the log:

```
07-03 15:19:58.633  28461-28461/jahirfiquitiva.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: jahirfiquitiva.project, PID: 28461
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@29f09d20
            at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1282)
            at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:599)
            at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:538)
            at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1176)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15239)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14175)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14197)
            at android.view.GhostView.onDraw(GhostView.java:52)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15239)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14175)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14197)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14967)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14170)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14197)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14967)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
            at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewOverlay.java:219)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15248)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2906)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14175)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14197)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2536)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

This is the code to open the other activity and save the picture as cache:

```
private void openViewer(WallpapersAdapter.WallsHolder wallsHolder, int index, final HashMap<String, String> data) {

        final Intent intent = new Intent(wallsActivity, ViewerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("wallUrl", data.get(WallpapersActivity.WALL));
        intent.putExtra("wallName", data.get(WallpapersActivity.NAME));
        intent.putExtra("transitionName", ViewCompat.getTransitionName(wallsHolder.wall));

        //save image from drawable
        //get its path and send it to activity
        Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(wallsHolder.wall.getDrawable());
        //Convert to byte array and send to the other activity

        Log.e("Resolution", bitmap.getWidth() + "x" + bitmap.getHeight());
        try {
            //Write file
            String filename = "bitmap.png";
            FileOutputStream stream = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            //Cleanup
            stream.close();
            bitmap.recycle();

            //Pop intent
            intent.putExtra("image", filename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                this, wallsHolder.wall, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(wallsHolder.wall));
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

    }

    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

What could I do to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you should save the bitmap into a real object reference, and not in cache. The cache might be allowed to free the bitmap when it's not being used anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that once in a while your bitmap gets into the recycled state just before the `Canvas` gets a chance to draw onto it here `drawable.draw(canvas);`.

A quick solution should be not to call `bitmap.recycle();`, which is not strictly required for [android >2.3.3](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html#recycle). If you still want to reclaim this memory forcefully, you'll have to find a way to check when the bitmap is indeed no longer needed (i.e., `Canvas` had a chance to finish its drawing operations).

Answer (score 5):

Move `bitmap.recycle();` to another place in the code where this bitmap is really no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by adding this:

```
Glide.with(activity).clear(view);
```

before load the image:

```
Glide.with(activity)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .apply(options)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
                .error(R.drawable.not_found)
                .into(view);
```

See docs:

http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/resourcereuse.html

http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/resourcereuse.html#cannot-draw-a-recycled-bitmap

Comment: Thank you sir. That doc saved me. But I would suggest to load into a target instead of the view and within `onLoadCleared` of that target, call `clear`. Calling clear like this will lessen the performance and the images will blink.

Answer (score 1):

Use this custom ImageView class

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {
 
    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
 
    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
 
    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        try {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(MyImageView.class.getSimpleName(), "Catch Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap");
        }
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about canvas (I don't use animations that often) but if you don't find any way to fix this, you could try using this library instead: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/shared-element-activity-transition